# creating a tab panel in extjs4 with different stores that loads only upon the particular tab is selected

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I'm using extjs4 and I'm trying to create a tab panel, that each tab has a different grid that loads data from a store. (each grid different store)
I would like to load the particular store only when the user clicks on the respective tab.
I don't see how I can catch the user click on the panel.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar performance loading issue and failed to solve it with `deferredRender`. You have to add the event `activate` for the tab you want to load when the tab is activated :

```
{
        title: 'tab2',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        html : 'A simple tab',
        listeners: {
                'activate' : function(){ 
                    store2.load(); 
                },
        }

}
```

Worked fine for me even if it's a temporary solution. Extjs 4.1 should improve loading/rendering performances. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

**Ext.TabPanel** has config option **deferredRender**. May be it helps you.
Documentation:
true by default to defer the rendering of child items to the browsers DOM until a tab is activated. false will render all contained items as soon as the layout is rendered. If there is a significant amount of content or a lot of heavy controls being rendered into panels that are not displayed by default, setting this to true might improve performance.

**Update:** Also look at **autoLoad** config option in **Ext.data.JsonStore**, it should be false.

Comment: I checked and deferredRender is true by default. So it helps me just to avoid the need to render, but doesn't avoid the need to load the store. What I'm looking for is a place to put the store.load() when the user clicks the respective tab

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the panel by placing `setActiveItem()` in tab handler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out, I just needed to have deferredRender=true and to add the respective store.load()  on the beforerender event on every tab:

```
    var lowerTabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        deferredRender: true,
        items: [
            {
            title: 'tab1',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            html : 'A simple tab',
            listeners: {
                    'beforerender' : function(){ 
                        store1.load(); 
                    },
            }

           },
            {
            title: 'tab2',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            html : 'A simple tab',
            listeners: {
                    'beforerender' : function(){ 
                        store2.load(); 
                    },
            }

           },
        ]
    });
```